# Hapi.js Subdomain Routing to Plugins

Tags: javascript, node.js, subdomain, url-routing, hapi.js

I am looking for a way to route different subdomains to different plugins. I looked through the [API docs](http://hapijs.com/api), and didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: `server.route(options)` takes `vhost` parameter. For each subdomain, you can create its own server with related vhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a simple class to create plugins that only work on certain subdomains. Here it is.

```
var Plugin = function(attributes, routes) {
    // Add our routes to the server
    this.register = function(plugin, options, next) {
        // Loop through the selected servers and add the routes
        plugin.servers.forEach(function(server) {
            // Loop through the routes and add the vhost option
            routes.map(function(route) {
                route.vhost = attributes.vhosts.map(function(vhost) {
                     return vhost + "." + server.info.host;
                });
            });

            // Add the routes
            server.route(routes);
        });
        next();
    };

    // Add our attributes
    this.register.attributes = attributes;
};
```

Then you can make a new plugin and specify the subdomains easily. Example:

```
var plugin = new Plugin([
    // Your route or routes here
], {
    vhosts: ["array", "of", "subdomains"]
});
```

Comment: I'm quite new to happijs and I'm trying to make it possible to allow subdomain registration for clients. Each client has own subdomain. The problem with this method is that you need to load all client subdomain tokens and pass them as an array to vhosts. How to allow * wildcard subdomains and check on request if the subdomain is in the DB or Redis for example?

Comment: @PavelNikolov did you got something on this ?? i need same kind of setup